# Странное поведение форм

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть react-код:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHttp } from '../.././hooks/http.hooks';

function ChangeProfile() {
    const { loading, request, error } = useHttp();
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});

    useEffect(async() => {
        const email = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).email;
        const password = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).password;
        const data = await request('http://localhost:5500/api/auth/profile_to_change',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    user: {
                        email,
                        password
                    }
                })
            }
        ); // Получение данных с сервера

        setProfile(data.profile);
    }, []);

    function changeForm(key) {
        return function(ev) {
            const newProfile = profile;
            newProfile[key] = ev.target.value;
            setProfile(newProfile);
        }
    }

    return (
        <section className="changeProfile">
            <div className="container">
                <table className="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Имя пользователя</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value={profile.name} onInput={changeForm('name')} /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Описание аккаунта</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value={profile.descr} onInput={changeForm('descr')} /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Телефон</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value={profile.phone} onInput={changeForm('phone')} /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Сайт</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value={profile.site} onInput={changeForm('site')} /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value={profile.email} onInput={changeForm('email')} /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <input type="button" value="Сохранить" />
                </table>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}

export default ChangeProfile;
```

Почему-то при попытке изменить input он просто не меняется, а свойства в объекте `profile` меняются максимум на одну букву от исходных. Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Сделай это:**

```js
const newProfile = { ...profile }  // Он создает новый объект.
// или же
const newProfile = Object.assign({}, profile)

newProfile[key] = ev.target.value
setProfile(newProfile)
```

**Не этот:**

```js
const newProfile = profile   // Он использует тот же объект. // неправильный
newProfile[key] = ev.target.value
setProfile(newProfile)
```

Вы напрямую изменяете исходные данные. Итак, React не может обнаружить изменения.